# Конвертация text/csv в blob [Angular 7/Java]

Tags: java, angular2, typescript, csv, angular

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь сконвентировать text/csv в blob, чтобы пользователь имел возможность скачать csv файл по кнопке.

Чем располагаю:
Есть API (Java 8 с RESTEasy), при обращении к одному из POST методов, на выходе возвращается text/csv :

[image: Заголовки ответа в POSTMAN]
[image: Тело ответа в POSTMAN]
[image: Код метода в API на Java (jax-rs)]

Есть веб клиент на Angular 7 и речь пойдет о проблеме в нем... 
При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает следующий код:

```
 exportSourceTableToCsv() {

  this.api.postExportToCsv(this.tableSource.toTable())
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => this.saveFile(res));
 }

 public postExportToCsv(table: Table): Observable<any> {

 return this.httpClient.post<any>( apiConfig.EXPORT_TO_CSV, table);
 }

 saveFile(response) {
 //Вот тут я так понимаю проблемное место
 const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: 'text/csv' });
 saveAs(blob, "table.csv"); //Плагин file-saver из npm для сохранения файлов.
 }
```

При вызове последнего метода выводится ошибка:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://localhost:4200/table/export","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/table/export","error":{"error":{},"text":"1;2;33\r\n23;23;33\r\n213;321;33\r\n123;3;33\r\n213;123;33\r\n"}}
at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
at zone.js:892
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17280)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
```

[image: Ответ как в Postman с браузера (превью такое же)]

Как это можно исправить? Видел много примеров именно с таким же подходом, должно работать

Пробовал указывать явно charset и еще text в качестве типа источника при создании Blob - не помогло. Тип возвращаемого значения для метода в API мне не сильно принципиален, но хотелось бы использовать предназначенный для передачи CSV - text/csv

Спасибо!

Comment: `this.httpClient.post<any>( apiConfig.EXPORT_TO_CSV, table, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })`  - однозначно вам сервер не обычный json возвращает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
return this.httpClient
  .post<any>( apiConfig.EXPORT_TO_CSV, table, 
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' }),
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
  .subscribe(file => saveAs(file, "table.csv"));
```

Comment: Надо еще добавить, что проблема таится в ангуляровском http клиенте. Он считает такой формат просто текстом, нужно использовать нативный клиент